# How to use a different content type as json in express

Tags: express, content-type

Is there a way to let express handle a different Content-Type as json format, when the Content-Type is different then application/json ?

For my project the data send to the backend is send as json format but needs to be in a different content type. Depending on the form and version we have different content-types: 'application/xxx.yyy.zzz.formname.v1+json'

Comment: Did you check the [options](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)?

Answer (score 0):

with the tip from @jonrsharpe this worked for me

app.use(express.json({ type: ['application/json','application/vnd.xxx.yyy.formname.v1+json'] }));